# Why do consecutive .bak full backup files increase in size?

Tags: sql-server-2016, backup

First, this is NOT a duplicate of [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139776/why-is-bak-file-size-increasing-doubling-with-each-consecutive-backup-on-sql-se). In that question the person was over-writing the file each time and the solution is to use INIT or NOINIT.

In my case we are generating a unique filename with each backup - a timestamp is appended to the filename.

We have an agent job that runs full backups nightly for about 20 databases. For about a week, 1 database seems to be increasing in size significantly each night.

We run a second agent job that runs log backups every 15 minutes but stops running between about 11pm and 5am. Usually first thing in the morning the log backups are large and then their size is small until people start working and then they're a variety of sizes.

All of this has been working without issue for years.

Only one database out of the 20 is showing this issue - each night's full backup is significantly larger than the prior night.

The log file backups are working for this database and all the others.

We have an availability group with three replicas. Two are set up to fail over to each other and the third replica is read-only for heavy queries, data extracts and reporting. The AG console shows green checkmarks all the way down the page for all servers.

The database in question is the largest out of the 20. Normal full backup is about 25GB. It slowly increased as follows: 33, 35, 36, 41, 47, 54, 64, 73 GB.

In contrast, for all 14 backups prior to this issue, file size was fairly steady around 25GB.

I have just paused all log backups for all database and issued a full backup to the affected database and that last full backup is 76GB.

Comment: What is the size of the data file and the log file of the database? What were they when the backup was only 25 GB?

Comment: @J.D. - currently data file is 207GB and log is 220GB.

Comment: You should add updates like that to your original Post so more people see it. The next couple of times your backup file grows significantly, keep an eye on if your data and log files are growing as well, and please let us know.

Comment: 3 things to check since you ruled out that you are not writing to the same file  - 1. data growth (if data is being written excessively due to some app bug), 2. Index fragmentation is very high (a rebuild or reorg can help) and 3. if LOB columns are added recently (schema changed occurred recently)

Comment: Thanks @KinShah .. we have nightly jobs to check index defrag and fix once a threshold is reached. These have worked for years but I will double check. There was a bug fix deployed a couple days before this started - we are checking changes made by that (which are expected to be unrelated). Last is the app bug, which I am hoping is not the case, but starting to this this might be the problem. Log file size is approx 220GB also - despite log backups succeeding. Seems massive at the moment.

Comment: "*Log file size is approx 220GB also - despite log backups succeeding.*" - The log file isn't going to automatically shrink when the backups succeed. Likely either a single large transaction occurred at some point to grow the log file, or multipe transactions occurred between when the log backups ran (likely during your 11pm to 5am window) that added up enough to grow the log file. Again, you should monitor your data and log file growth the next few times the full backups grow, so you can deduce if your database growing is the source.

Comment: @J.D. - I should have added - log file is 99% utilised too .. so very strange it is about 3x size of data file, but apparently legitimately so.

Comment: Does the [`log_reuse_wait_desc` column in `sys.databases`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) say anything?

Comment: @J.D. - it says `AVAILABILITY_REPLICA` - but when I checked a couple days ago, and checked again now, the AG Dashboard shows green ticks across the board - nothing has faulted. There is nothing in the Log Send Queue column and the Redo Queue Size (KB) shows a queue for only 2 databases with max value being only 130kb.

Comment: @J.D. - The AG Dashboard shows the affected database in sync. It has a redo queue of 3kb to one replica and 5kb to the other and a wait time of 1s in both cases. Pinal Dave has an article about this `AVAILABILITY_REPLICA` value. One cause may be long-running transactions, but there are none. His other causes are bad network connection (but if I had that, wouldn't the dashboard show a bit of a queue?) and that the target server has run out of worker threads, with solution to reboot.

Comment: @J.D. - I've managed to resolve the issue. Fundamentally your suggestion to check log_reuse_wait_desc put me on the right path. Even though it was the backup file of the data file that was growing, somehow the log files were linked. The two primary AG replicas both showed they were waiting on `AVAILABILITY_REPLICA` but a third replica - read only - showed it was waiting on `ACTIVE_TRANSACTION`. That said, when I queried - no active transactions. Finally, rebooted that replica and all resolved although log file remained 99% in use and most VLFs status 2 despite backups. Shrink file still worked

Comment: FWIW, you can confirm what's actually running on your SQL Servers by running [`sp_WhoIsActive`](http://whoisactive.com) next time. Glad you resolved your issue though.

Comment: @J.D. - I used `sp_who2` - there were three active sessions. For the first, I asked users to log out; session ended. For the second, it was a service account. I killed the session. For the third, it was my SQL session as DBA. I ran `rollback` on every open tab (and all failed) - I'm not sure whether `sp_whoIsActive` would have given me additional info? I will explore that one today. It seems to me that the DB got confused - thinking an AG sync had not completed when in fact it had.

Comment: `sp_WhoIsActive` will give you a ton of more information than `sp_who2` including specifically what the active queries are waiting on, and if they're being blocked by any other queries and which queries those are, in addition to some information on resources consumed by those active queries. It can also tell you the percent complete of certain commands such as backups.

Comment: Just to note this issue occurred twice more in the 9 months since the question was asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a particular issue where `sys.databases.log_reuse_wait` was reporting `AVAILABILITY_REPLICA` on two replicas in the Availability Group, and `ACTIVE_TRANSACTION` on the third replica.

In my case, trying to determine the active transaction yielded no results - read the whole comment thread against the question for details.

In the end I rebooted that replica and all resolved.

**In summary**

The *log* file was being held open by an active transaction (or at least the database thought so) and this somehow was flowing on to the *data* file full backup filesize growing nightly.

Identifying the root cause came through checking `sys.databases.log_reuse_wait` - with thanks to @J.D. in the comments for the suggestion -

And the resolution came through rebooting the affected replica (because I could not actually find any active transaction to `kill`, despite the `log_reuse_wait` message saying `ACTIVE_TRANSACTION`).